# Dictionary with costs by weight

Tags: python, dictionary, range

today I would like to embed shipping price table to python dictionary and I have not idea how to start.

### **What I have?**

```
I have table with shipping costs and zones.

    +-----------+------+---------+--------+
    |  weight   | Asia | America | Europe |
    +-----------+------+---------+--------+
    | 0-500     |   10 |      15 |      5 |
    | 501-1000  |   13 |      18 |      8 |
    | 1001-2000 |   16 |      21 |     11 |
    +-----------+------+---------+--------+
```

### What I have tried?

```
shipping_costs =    [

                        {
                            "min_w":    0,
                            "max_w":    500,
                            "asia":     10,
                            "america":  15,
                            "europe":   5
                        },
                        {
                            "min_w":    501,
                            "max_w":    1000,
                            "asia":     13,
                            "america":  18,
                            "europe":   8
                        },
                        {
                            "min_w":    1001,
                            "max_w":    2000,
                            "asia":     16,
                            "america":  21,
                            "europe":   11
                        }

                    ]

product_weight = 600

for zone in shipping_costs:
    if zone['min_w'] <= product_weight <= zone['max_w']:
        print('Asia: {}, America: {}, Europe: {}'.format(zone['asia'],zone['america'],zone['europe']))
```

And... And it works but I have doubts about search method. Is it properly way? Or is better tool to finding ranges?

Answer (score 2):

It's quite OK, but you need to correct your edge conditions - check for "less than or equal" instead of "less than", or cases like `500` will produce incorrect results:

```
if zone['min_w'] <= product_weight <= zone['max_w']:
```

Also, there's a typo - the closing parenthesis of the `print` function must of course come after the `.format()` method:

```
    print('Asia: {}, America: {}, Europe: {}'.format(zone['asia'],zone['america'],zone['europe']))
```

Also possible:

```
   print('Asia: {asia}, America: {america}, Europe: {europe}'.format(**zone))
```

Comment: Oh thank you. What is that `0` which you typed in second possible format?

Comment: Ok now I understand everything

Comment: I had to leave for a while, sorry. But in the meantime I remembered how to properly access items of a dictionary in a format string.

Comment: But now it isn't that obvious for me. Can you shortly explain what you did?

Comment: `**` is the "keyword unpacking" operator, allowing you to pass a dictionary into a function or method as if you had provided all of its contents manually. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1769403/20670 for some good explanations.